# Swift UI Navigation View not switching the whole screen

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to create a simple `NavigationView`. But with code outside of it. Like this:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            NavigationView {
                VStack{
                    
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("HEllo")
                    } label: {
                        Text("Click me")
                    }
                    .navigationViewStyle(.columns)
                }
                .navigationTitle("A Title")
                

            }
            
        }
       
    }
}
```

I do that so the navigation Title is below the item outside the `NavigationView`.

This code gives me this:
[Image because I am not allowed to insert images yet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8gmO.png)

When I click on the `NavigationLink` though I see this:

[The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Tcg.png)

As you see the `RoundedRectangle` still is viewable at top of the screen. How can I fix that, so that the `Rectangle` disappears and the Destination is viewable in full screen?

Comment: Why do you have that RoundedRectangle outside of the NavigationView?

Comment: @GogaBarabadze it has to do something with the app I am building. I had the idea of an infomation that is shown where the rounded rectangle is right now

Answer (score 0):

Set navigation view first, You have to put everything inside the navigation view.

```
NavigationView { // Here
    VStack{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        VStack{ // Remove from above
```

Comment: I tried this as well but then the navigation title is above the rounded rectangle so this is not possible sadly.

Comment: Then you have apply hacky solution there is no good way or maybe you have to use custom navigation title instead of default. Just add text next after rectangle

Answer (score 0):

The `RoundedRectangle` is still visible because it is outside of the `NavigationView`, only the content of the `NavigationView` will move with the `NavigationLink`

Something you could do is to use the `toolbar` of the `NavigationView` to place items on the top of the screen

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                Text("HEllo")
            } label: {
                Text("Click me")
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(.columns)
            
            .navigationTitle("A Title")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is indeed working. After hearing all your answers though I think that is not a good idea to do, so I solved the problem by showing a sheet to the user. I am really thank you after all.